# Is there biblical reference to Michael, the archangel’s role and being?

Tags: biblical-basis, angels, michael

I am looking for the biblical references to Michael the angel ? And what are/were his/her role? There are some christian groups that attributes  Michael same with Jesus. Is there any biblical reference to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, [Jude 9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jude%201&version=NASB) says:

> But Michael the archangel, when he disputed with the devil and argued about the body of Moses, did not dare pronounce against him a railing judgment, but said, "The Lord rebuke you!"

From that verse, it would seem to be hard to equate Michael and Jesus.

The only other reference to "archangel" I know of is in [1 Thessalonians 4:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians+4:16&version=NASB):

> For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first.

That verse seems to indicate the "voice of the archangel" will announce Christ's (
the Lord Himself) return - again listed as a separate being.

Answer (score 2):

**References to Michael**

> Dan_10:13  But the prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me one and twenty days: but, lo, Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help me; and I remained there with the kings of Persia.

NOTE: the word one is a gross misinterpretation of the word echad in this situation which means first using Strong's Dictionary. One of the chief princes actually translated correctly means the First of the chief princes.

> Dan_10:21  But I will shew thee that which is noted in the scripture of truth: and there is none that holdeth with me in these things, but Michael your prince.
>
> Dan_12:1  And at that time shall Michael stand up, the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time thy people shall be delivered, every one that shall be found written in the book.
>
> 1Th_4:16  For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first:
>
> Jud_1:9  Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil he disputed about the body of Moses, durst not bring against him a railing accusation, but said, The Lord rebuke thee.
>
> Rev_12:7  And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,

**The roles of Michael of the Archangel**

**#1 He stands for the people of God**

> Dan 12:1  And at that time shall Michael stand up, ***the great prince which standeth for the children of thy people***: and there shall be a time of trouble, such as never was since there was a nation even to that same time: and at that time ***thy people shall be delivered***, every one that shall be found written in the book.

He stands for the people of God (an advocate) and an example of him standing for them is in Jude 1:9 below

> Jude 1:9 Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil he disputed about the body of Moses, durst not bring against him a *railing accusation*, but said, ***The Lord rebuke thee.***

The words translated railing is blasphēmia which Strong's Dictionary says mean blaspheme or evil speaking. Michael did not bring a blasphemous accusation but said the Lord rebuke thee. He was not afraid of satan as some would try to make us think but dared not to bring a blaphemous accusation which is sin.

**Jesus the Lord is our advocate**

> Zechariah 3:1,2 And he shewed me Joshua the high priest standing before the angel of the LORD, and Satan standing at his right hand to ***resist him***. And the **LORD** said unto Satan,***The LORD rebuke thee***, O Satan; even the LORD that hath chosen Jerusalem rebuke thee: is not this a brand plucked out of the fire?

In this scenario we have the Lord being the advocate of Joshua and saying the same thing Michael said to satan. It seems as though Jesus has the same office with Michael or maybe they are the same person.

**#2 He is the captain of the Lord's Host**

> Revelation 12:7 And there was war in heaven: **Michael and his angels** fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels,

He leads the angels in the battle with satan thus he is the captain. His position as archangel means chief of the angels (check your Strong's dictionary)

> Joshua 5:13-15 And it came to pass, when Joshua was by Jericho, that he lifted up his eyes and looked, and, behold, there stood a man over against him with his sword drawn in his hand: and Joshua went unto him, and said unto him, Art thou for us, or for our adversaries? And he said, Nay; but as **captain of the host of the LORD** am I now come. And Joshua fell on his face to the earth, ***and did worship***, and said unto him, What saith ***my lord*** unto his servant? And the **captain of the LORD'S host** said unto Joshua, ***Loose thy shoe from off thy foot; for the place whereon thou standest is holy***. And Joshua did so.

Here we see that Michael cannot be a literal angel since he accepts worship as God. No angel coming from God accepts worship:

> Rev 19:10  And I fell at his feet to worship him. And he said unto me, See thou do it not: I am thy fellowservant, and of thy brethren that have the testimony of Jesus: worship God: for the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.

**#3 He is the Chief Messenger**

The word angel means messenger so therefore he must be the Arch Messenger. Michael is not an a literal angel but a messenger. the word messenger and the word angel are the same in both greek and hebrew.

Strong's Hebrew dictionary

messenger = malak

angel     = malak

Strong's Greek Dictionary

messenger = aggellō

angel     = aggellō

**What about 1thess 4:16?**

> 1Th_4:16  For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, **with the voice of the archangel**, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first:
>
> Joh 5:25  Verily, verily, I say unto you, The hour is coming, and now is, when the dead shall hear the **voice of the Son of God:** and they that hear shall live.

The event described here is the Second coming. With the parallel produced by John 5:25 and 1 thess 4:16 it is hard to think Jesus the Son of God is not Michael the Archangel shouting with the trump of God.

**ALWAYS REMEMBER MICHAEL IS NOT A LITERAL ANGEL HE IS A CHIEF MESSENGER.**

Comment: Hebres 1:6-7: And again, when God brings his firstborn into the world, he says,

“Let all God’s angels worship him.”

7 In speaking of the angels he says,

“He makes his angels spirits,
    and his servants flames of fire.”. I feel this verse indicates Jesus cannot be an angel.

Comment: Yes Jesus is not an angel but a messenger (I have already stated this in my response). Jesus is God fully God. For in Him lies the fullness of the Godhead. Anyone not accepting this fact must start ignoring a lot of verses however no one should ignore the verses I have above. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: And some of the above references says Michael is an angel as per Jude 9 (warren's answer). So if Michael is an angel and if Jesus is not an angel, then how Michael is Jesus (your conclusion)

Comment: Let me solve the confusion quickly. Jesus is an angel(messenger) check Malachi 3:1, Messenger of the Covenant. Jesus is not an angel (CREATED BEING eg Gabriel) check John 1:1. I really pray that you would understand me. Malachi 3:1 has Jesus as Messenger of the Covenant. The word messenger there is malak in hebrew which can also mean angel. There is so much evidence of michael being Jesus. Infact I wil submit a completely different answer with stronger connections between Jesus and Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the reference that @warren has given.  The other passage believed to refer to him is in Daniel 10.  Note that the word angel isn't used here - he is called a prince - but context *may* imply it.

Comment: Michael is also referenced in Revelation